# TemplateSyntaxError at /polls/ Invalid block tag on line 27

Tags: python, html, django

I'm currently working through the Django tutorial and just finished part 3, but am getting this error when trying to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/:

TemplateSyntaxError at /polls/
Invalid block tag on line 27: '<span', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
Invalid block tag on line 27: '<span', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Error during template rendering

I think there's a problem with my views.py file, but I've copy/pasted everything from the tutorial trying to avoid these issues. This is the view that the error is being thrown on:

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

I'm very new to this so if I'm missing something obvious, please point it out.

index.html:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url ‘polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem lie here : `<a href="{% url ‘polls:detail' question.id %}">`, more precisely in `‘polls:detail'`

Notice how the first quote is not the same character as the second one. You probably meant :

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">`
```

Comment: Fixes one problem, raises another: Could not parse the remainder: '</span><span' from '</span><span' - appreciate any follow up on this

Comment: Clarification: error during template rendering. This part was in red on line 22:

{% url </span><span class="s5">‘polls:</span><span class="s4">detail’ question.id %}

Comment: Please edit your question, I see no `<span>` in the given snippets.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.html file try adding {% endfor %} in new line, I think this should fix.

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url ‘polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: There is actually an `{% endfor %}` at the end of the `<li>` line.

Comment: Moving it to a new line solved the first problem but created another: Could not parse the remainder: '‘polls:detail'' from '‘polls:detail''. Thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes, don't put {% endfor %} in the same line after </li>, press enter and shift it to a new line

Comment: what is the name of that url in urls.py?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the `{% endfor %}` is on a new line or not. The error message was different just because of how the template parser works. Your problem lie in your quote of `‘polls:detail'`.